# Why do Resolve and ForAll fail with trigonometric expressions?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, resolve

Why `Resolve` is not able to solve this [problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293819/the-following-three-equal-frequency-oscillations-are-superimposed-2sint0-3-5)? Similarly `Solve` and `Reduce` are not able to do it.

The first code returns back the input, the second one keeps running forever.

```
Resolve[ForAll[t, 2 Sin[t + 3/10] + 5 Cos[t + π/4] + Cos[t - 31/10] == 
   a Sin[t] + b Cos[t]]]
```

---

```
Resolve[ForAll[t, 2 Sin[t + 3/10] + 5 Cos[t + π/4] + Cos[t - 31/10] == 
   a Cos[b + t]], Reals]
```

Answer (score 6):

Up to the documentation to `Resolve` (see the "Details" section)

> Resolve[expr] can in principle always eliminate quantifiers if expr contains only polynomial equations and inequalities over the reals or complexes.
> Resolve[expr] can in principle always eliminate quantifiers for any Boolean expression expr.

, the commands are mainly oriented towards polynomials and Boolean expressions. In view of it we should to switch from trigonometry to polynomials by

```
Resolve[ForAll[{c, s}, TrigExpand[2 Sin[t + 3/10] + 5 Cos[t + \[Pi]/4] + 
Cos[t - 31/10]] == a Sin[t] + b Cos[t] /. {Sin[t] -> s, Cos[t] -> c}],Reals]
```

> `5/Sqrt[2] + a - 2 Cos[1/10]^3 - 31 Cos[1/10]^30 Sin[1/10] +  6 Cos[1/10] Sin[1/10]^2 + 4495 Cos[1/10]^28 Sin[1/10]^3 -  169911 Cos[1/10]^26 Sin[1/10]^5 +  2629575 Cos[1/10]^24 Sin[1/10]^7 -  20160075 Cos[1/10]^22 Sin[1/10]^9 +  84672315 Cos[1/10]^20 Sin[1/10]^11 -  206253075 Cos[1/10]^18 Sin[1/10]^13 +  300540195 Cos[1/10]^16 Sin[1/10]^15 -  265182525 Cos[1/10]^14 Sin[1/10]^17 +  141120525 Cos[1/10]^12 Sin[1/10]^19 -  44352165 Cos[1/10]^10 Sin[1/10]^21 +  7888725 Cos[1/10]^8 Sin[1/10]^23 -  736281 Cos[1/10]^6 Sin[1/10]^25 + 31465 Cos[1/10]^4 Sin[1/10]^27 -  465 Cos[1/10]^2 Sin[1/10]^29 + Sin[1/10]^31 ==  0 && -(5/Sqrt[2]) + b - Cos[1/10]^31 - 6 Cos[1/10]^2 Sin[1/10] +  465 Cos[1/10]^29 Sin[1/10]^2 + 2 Sin[1/10]^3 -  31465 Cos[1/10]^27 Sin[1/10]^4 + 736281 Cos[1/10]^25 Sin[1/10]^6 -  7888725 Cos[1/10]^23 Sin[1/10]^8 +  44352165 Cos[1/10]^21 Sin[1/10]^10 -  141120525 Cos[1/10]^19 Sin[1/10]^12 +  265182525 Cos[1/10]^17 Sin[1/10]^14 -  300540195 Cos[1/10]^15 Sin[1/10]^16 +  206253075 Cos[1/10]^13 Sin[1/10]^18 -  84672315 Cos[1/10]^11 Sin[1/10]^20 +  20160075 Cos[1/10]^9 Sin[1/10]^22 -  2629575 Cos[1/10]^7 Sin[1/10]^24 +  169911 Cos[1/10]^5 Sin[1/10]^26 - 4495 Cos[1/10]^3 Sin[1/10]^28 +  31 Cos[1/10] Sin[1/10]^30 == 0`

and then

```
Solve[%, {a, b}, Reals]
```

> `{{a -> -(5/Sqrt[2]) + 2 Cos[1/10]^3 + 31 Cos[1/10]^30 Sin[1/10] -  6 Cos[1/10] Sin[1/10]^2 - 4495 Cos[1/10]^28 Sin[1/10]^3 +  169911 Cos[1/10]^26 Sin[1/10]^5 -  2629575 Cos[1/10]^24 Sin[1/10]^7 +  20160075 Cos[1/10]^22 Sin[1/10]^9 -  84672315 Cos[1/10]^20 Sin[1/10]^11 +  206253075 Cos[1/10]^18 Sin[1/10]^13 -  300540195 Cos[1/10]^16 Sin[1/10]^15 +  265182525 Cos[1/10]^14 Sin[1/10]^17 -  141120525 Cos[1/10]^12 Sin[1/10]^19 +  44352165 Cos[1/10]^10 Sin[1/10]^21 -  7888725 Cos[1/10]^8 Sin[1/10]^23 +  736281 Cos[1/10]^6 Sin[1/10]^25 -  31465 Cos[1/10]^4 Sin[1/10]^27 + 465 Cos[1/10]^2 Sin[1/10]^29 -  Sin[1/10]^31,  b -> 5/Sqrt[2] + Cos[1/10]^31 + 6 Cos[1/10]^2 Sin[1/10] -  465 Cos[1/10]^29 Sin[1/10]^2 - 2 Sin[1/10]^3 +  31465 Cos[1/10]^27 Sin[1/10]^4 -  736281 Cos[1/10]^25 Sin[1/10]^6 +  7888725 Cos[1/10]^23 Sin[1/10]^8 -  44352165 Cos[1/10]^21 Sin[1/10]^10 +  141120525 Cos[1/10]^19 Sin[1/10]^12 -  265182525 Cos[1/10]^17 Sin[1/10]^14 +  300540195 Cos[1/10]^15 Sin[1/10]^16 -  206253075 Cos[1/10]^13 Sin[1/10]^18 +  84672315 Cos[1/10]^11 Sin[1/10]^20 -  20160075 Cos[1/10]^9 Sin[1/10]^22 +  2629575 Cos[1/10]^7 Sin[1/10]^24 -  169911 Cos[1/10]^5 Sin[1/10]^26 + 4495 Cos[1/10]^3 Sin[1/10]^28 -  31 Cos[1/10] Sin[1/10]^30}}`

Comment: Finally, `FullSimplify[%]` results in `{{a -> -(5/Sqrt[2]) + 2 Cos[3/10] + Sin[31/10], 
  b -> 5/Sqrt[2] + Cos[31/10] + 2 Sin[3/10]}}`.